# MySQL query optimization - functions or subqueries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've written a query that takes 13+ seconds to run that includes multiple sub queries. Would it be beneficial to create a function for each of these sub queries and call them, or would the difference be negligible?

Comment: Instead of functions you can create some [views](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)

Comment: Probably not. Rewrite your query, or perhaps create temporary tables. Share your query along with a description of your tables, we might be able to help.